# What is the internal format of PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, format, geohash

PostGIS stores its geometry entities as long strings:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(32.0 34.0)',4326);
                  st_geomfromtext
----------------------------------------------------
 0101000020E610000000000000000040400000000000004140
```

For nearby points like (32.0 34.0) and (32.01 34.01), the string has a common prefix `0101000020E6100000` which might suggest a suggest a [geohash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) technique:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(32.01 34.01)',4326);
                  st_geomfromtext
----------------------------------------------------
 0101000020E6100000E17A14AE47014040E17A14AE47014140
```

Any idea what is the storage format of PostGIS geometries?

Comment: PostGIS is open source, if ever in doubt read the source.

Comment: @NathanW Sure. I was looking for a reference to an explanation, rather than code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is not a string format. It is a binary format using integers, double precission and special bytes used for flags.

What you see as output above is not the internal format but the wkb format represented as hex numbers

The internal format is described here:
http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/browser/trunk/liblwgeom/g_serialized.txt

The document is written before postgis 2.0 when g-serialized also is used for the geometey type. But as far as I know it is the same.