# Understand way field (type geometry) in planet_osm_polygon

Tags: polygon, openstreetmap, geometry, well-known-text

I'm new to **QGIS** and I'm using **PostGreSQL** and **QGIS DB Manager** to get information from the polygon_osm tables.

I'm currently working on the _polygon table and I'd like to get the coordinates for each point in the polygons.

Here is the problem I am facing:

**I am trying to figure out what the "way" field is. When I display the whole table it says "POLYGON" and when I display a specific entry I have very long series of numbers and letters (0-9, A-F) like "0103000020110F00000100000051010000713D0AD7BBDCB..."**

and so on (fewer zeros on the right). I'm looking for a way to get a human-readable field, by which I mean coordinates of the points specifying the vertices of the polygon, or id linked to another table (I'm not sure what is stored in this field). The field type is **geometry(Geometry,3857)**. I have a warning message saying "There is no entry in geometry_columns!", I don't know if it is related.

The geom_to_wkt function seems to be what I'm looking for but I am working on tables with millions of entries so I need to do this with a query in DB Manager and not just in the field calculator of the attribute table.

Comment: for your question about the geometries is [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/107804/81214) a related answer and a primary key needs to be present

Comment: Thanks for your help, the post was helpful, although the gserialized documentation is not very clear to me. I was able to identify patterns in the field, but I'm still not sure how to identify blocks (16 ? 32 ?) and I'm not sure if they correspond to latitude and longitude according to the geocash algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get a human-readable coordinate from a PostGIS geom field, you can create a new field and store there the geometry as a well-known text.

Workflow as follows:

- Open the attribute table of your polygon table and go to the field calculator
- Create a new field as text with the formel `geom_to_wkt( $geometry )`
- This will fill the field with something like this: **'MultiPolygon (((698810.86974609 5749870.81713066, 698614.863...'** which is in this example the representation of a multi-polygon with x and y coordinates for each vertex

**EDIT:**

To do this in the DB manager you need to create a field and update it with the [ST_AsText](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_AsText.html) function from PostGIS

the query looks like this:

```
ALTER TABLE my_schema.my_table
    ADD COLUMN wkt_geom text; -- instead of wkt_geom you can name it whatever you like 

Update   my_schema.my_table
    SET wkt_geom = ST_AsText(geom); -- if the geomtry column is named differently you need to change "geom" as well
```

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks ! Any idea as to how to do this with a query in DB manager ?

Comment: @Anne see my edit, hope it helps :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks a lot, it helps a great deal ! I had tried something like that but with the geom_to_wkt function, which did not work. One last thing : as you wrote it in your answer, I get something like (4136278.21 5478121.15, ...) where the comma is misplaced, because it is placed so as to have two digits. This may be an issue when I want to join with table with, say, the nodes table. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Anne Not need to worry. The format is POLYGON( x y , x y , ... you could create another field which only holds one pair of x and y values but to do this and how to, you would need to ask a new question after trying a bit around ;)